# How to get the specific <li> id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two pictures below. I'm not familiar about the Parent and Child in HTML. As you can see below there is a nested `<ul> <li>` (there are 2). The first picture is the my first `<ul>` and the second picture is my second `<ul>`. What I want to achieve here is upon clicking a specific button it will get the first `<ul> > <li> id`. I've been searching for two days about this problem of mine but unfortunately I didn't see an answer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pictures of code are in general a bad idea, Its way better for us to see your actual code.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. And then edit your question, to include code examples in text form, not just images. Also describe what you have tried so far to solve this. (“Nothing” is too little.)

Comment: And then, go research and read up on _DOM traversal_, that would be the main keyword here. jQuery has lots of methods for that, https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/, https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Comment: No need for jQuery here... a simple `document.querySelector` would do the trick !

Comment: @MartinAckermann i can' remember all the code that i've tried. I've undo everything. But I recreate one of them `$('#btnId').find('submenu2').closest('li:selected').attr('id')` but it returns undefined

Comment: `li:selected` makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is probably something like this :

```
var theIdYouAreSearchingFor = document.querySelector('.submenu2 .ui-state-active a').id
```

A little advice here : Stop building layouts with `table` this tag is not meant for this!

Comment: 3Dos i just change the `.submenu2` to `#submenu2` because it is ID not a class.. thanks